# Invite to CKShare and Accept CKShare without UICloudSharingController and without sending link with URL

Tags: cloudkit, cloudkit-sharing

Say I am making `Root <-> Child` application (i.e. `Manager <-> Employee`).

Say `Manager` has predefined email and already granted `userDiscoverability` application permission (via `CKContainer.requestApplicationPermission`).

When `Employee` starts application, initialisation sequence automatically creates `CKRecord` (i.e. Employee record for time tracking), `CKShare` and silently invites `Manager` to `CKShare`.

For achieving this I am using `CKContainer.discoverUserIdentity`, then `CKContainer.fetchShareParticipant`, then `CKModifyRecordsOperation` which saves both `CKRecord` and `CKShare`.

After initialisation flow in private database of `Employee` I have record type of `cloudkit.share` which has 2 participants, `Employee` itself and `Manager`. Acceptance status of `Manager` is **INVITED**. Also I have URL link which I got after saving `CKShare`.

Now on `Manager` side I want silently accept `CKShare` invitation in order to access `Employee` record (i.e. for time tracking).

---

How to **silently accept** `CKShare` invitation without need of sending URL link via email, Messages.app, without using UICloudSharingController, etc.?

Is it possible to **purely programmatically, silently, using CloudKit only** share `CKShare` from one side and accept it on other side?

Thank you!

Comment: Vlad, I too would like to do this, got a little further by opening the URL with code, but ran out of time to get anywhere with this. Did you hear any more? If I could I would pitch in on a reward to get an answer?

Comment: The key to the puzzle is that the other party needs to do the accepting, you can not do it for them, so you need to transmit the link come what may.

Comment: I created another `CKRecord` to keep `CKShare` URL. After creating share on `Employee` side the result URL saved into Public Database. `Manager` gets subscription notification that Public Database was changed. After fetching changes it opens URL programmatically. As result `CKShare` is accepted. It still prototype but seems working.)

Comment: Vlad, I have noticed you need to be really careful with the parent share on this in terms of timing. I too create a parent share and then assign it to the records I want share. But it seems to fail even after I have confirmed the parent share is readable if I don't give it a few seconds or so to complete.

Comment: Thanks for the info. It's defenetely help me out... But quick question, what do you do with the cloudkit.share record we get from fetchChangeZone? Is it just for notifying us of the "acceptance" status. Do we have the save it's token in the local database. I'm a bit confused on that... I would appreciate someone pointing me in the right direction. I can't find anyone mentioning that cloudkit.share record we get back and it breaks my current saving to my local database routine...

Comment: On receiving `CKDatabaseNotification` about changes in shared DB I am fetching all record zones in shared DB (aka `foreign user records`) and then fetching changes from all zones in shared DB using previously saved cursor (if any). Then updating local cache (CoreData DB) using custom merge logic.

Comment: Did you find a solution?